# User Profile & Logout links inaccessible from the 'badge' statistics page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, hyperlinks, navigation

This may be a nitpick, but as this site seems to be about improvements to SO, I thought I'd mention it anyway ;0)

Ive noticed that when I select a badge I received to observe it's meaning, the links at the top of the page are shorter by two, specifically the user profile link and the logout link.  Practically, this means that when I navigate to the badge page, the only way to get back to the user profile page is with the back button.

I realize this is a slight picky, however it could mean a lot more to someone else - as the insecurity some users feel when they are forced to navigate with the back button for fear of loosing their 'place' if that makes any sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed.  Thanks guys! :)